# $http headers("etag") returns incorrect value

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, playframework

I have 2 layers of REST APIs, first one is on top of a NoSQL DB, second one is on a Java Play Framework layer which in most cases is a pass-thru layer depending on the endpoint.

The endpoint I am calling is:

/record/id/{?identifier}

If I make a Postman call (Chrome REST client) to localhost:9000/record/id/myidentifier (Java Play layer) I do get a correct ETag value.

If I make a Postman call to localhost:9001/record/id/myidentifier (DB REST API layer) I do get a correct ETag value.

On the angularjs side I am using $http to retrieve the record and get the ETag value from the response headers (the call is made to the Java Play REST API), **but** the ETag is not the correct value, it's something else, it's in the correct format but the actual value is incorrect and I can't figure out why oh why...

Did anyone have similar issue? Is this some kind of caching issue? I am clueless at this time, it doesn't make any sense...

```
...more stuff here ...
var ETag = "";
recordService.recordById (id)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {
            ETag = headers ('ETag');

            recordService.changeRecordState (id, state, ETag, $scope.role)
                .success (function (data, status, headers) {
                    // All good reload data
                    $scope.runSearch();

                });
        });
```

The actual service:

```
this.recordById = function (id) {

    var endpoint = "/record/id/"

    return $http (
    {
        url: url + endpoint + id,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }
    })
}
```

Comment: I see a relative path in that service. What is 'url'? Is it actually 'localhost:9001' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was not included in the code snippets, the "url" is http://localhost:9000 which points to the Java Play endpoint. Full URL is http://localhost:9000/record/id/identifier which is correct.